# Can Oracle Flashback SCN be a negative value?

Tags: database, oracle, flashback

Is there a definition for SCN used in Oracle Flashback technology? I was wondering whether the SCN can take a negative value or is it an unsigned value.

Comment: You mean like [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#GUID-A2615547-94D2-4346-B156-64C534C5E9E4)? It doesn't explicitly say it can't be negative, but as an "monotonically increasing sequence" that is somewhat implied. [The maximum value is also documented](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76.htm#d1926268e300).

Comment: Also, if you have access to My Oracle Support, look at document ID 1431133.1 for an explanation of how the SCN is constructed; that also suggests it can't ever be negative.